# Remove duplicates in a PHP array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm using the Google API to extract data from Analytics. But I can't remove the duplicates in my array. I have checked the forum and array_unique functionalities seems to do the trick but I can't make it working. Any ideas?

Much appreciated!

#### THE CODE:

```
<?php
    $jsonurl = "URL";
    $json = file_get_contents($jsonurl,0,null,null);
    $arrayJson = json_decode($json, true);
    $arrayTable = $arrayJson['rows'];
?>
    <table style="border 1px solid" width="700px">
      <tr>
        <td>ID</td>
        <td>Source</td>
        <td>Medium</td>
        <td>Column 4</td>
        <td>Column 5</td>
        <td>Column 6</td>
        <td>Column 7</td>
        <td>Column 8</td>
     </tr>
    <?php  for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayTable); $i++) { ?> 
      <tr> 
       <?php  for($ii = 0; $ii < count($arrayTable[$i]); $ii++) { ?>
         <td> <?php print_r($arrayTable[$i][$ii]); ?></td>
       <?php  }  ?>
     </tr>
     <?php  } ?> 
   </table>
```

Comment: Your problem is due to incorrect usage of `array_unique` (or at least incorrect expectation of what it does), check my answer below to find out why.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [array_unique](https://www.php.net/array_unique) like below:

```
$input = array("a" => "green", "red", "b" => "green", "blue", "red");
$result = array_unique($input);
print_r($result);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [a] => green
    [0] => red
    [1] => blue
)
```

Comment: do i need to put it within my for statement or after? Both won't work when i define array_unique like this: $result = array_unique($arrayTable);   print_r($result)

Answer (score 0):

You must do it before the cycle.
For example:

```
$arrayTable = array_unique($arrayJson['rows']);
```

Comment: I have tried this solution but unfortunately it only shows 1 row (out of 1700) when there are only 4-5 duplicates. Thanks for help though!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is because you are trying to use `array_unique` on a multi-dimensional array. It is designed to only work on the first level of an array. For example:

```
$a = array('crazy', 'sane', 'mad', 'sane');

print_r( array_unique($a) );
```

The above will give:

```
array( 'crazy', 'sane', 'mad' );
```

However, if you try:

```
$a = array( 
  0 => array('crazy'), 
  1 => array('sane'), 
  2 => array('mad'), 
  3 => array('sane'),
);

print_r( array_unique($a) );
```

You will get:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => crazy ) )
```

This is because `array_unique` converts all values to strings before it does it's uniquification. In PHP all arrays produce the string `Array` when cast... This is why you only get one item.

The only way you will resolve this is if you choose to have one value representing your unique value and sort / uniquify based on this. The standard approach would be to set this value as the key of the array and that will automatically create a unique list.

For example, taking the multi-dimensional array from above, we can convert to a unique array by doing the following.

```
$u = array();
foreach ( $a as $key => $val ) {
  $u[reset($val)] = $val;
}

print_r( $u );
```

You will get:

```
Array ( 
  [crazy] => Array ( 
    [0] => crazy 
  ) 
  [sane] => Array ( 
    [0] => sane 
  ) 
  [mad] => Array ( 
    [0] => mad 
  ) 
)
```